# Can an IMocksControl create an IMockBuilder?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock

I'm having a problem where I wanted to use an IMocksControl to test multiple objects.  As this allows me to check function call order across several objects.

At the same time, I wanted to use an IMockBuilder to create a mock object with only a few methods mocked out.

Since it appears an IMockBuilder cannot be created from an IMocksControl, how can I achieve my goal?

I saw: public static void checkOrder(Object mock, boolean state) as static on EasyMock, but it's not clear to me if that's setting strict checking for only that mock object or for every mock object created using EasyMock.createMock.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to check the order across objects? Is the exact order really all that important?

It *sounds* like you are currently heading down a path I've travelled and luckily escaped from. It sounds like you are replicating the code in mocks and verifying exactly what happens. This is a bad way to test as you end up with very brittle tests that do not make it clear what the end result of the method is.

Instead try to only verify what is important and for multiple steps ask if the first step is important, or if what happens to the result is important. i.e.

```
void drive(Person driver, Car car) {
  driver.press(car.getAccelerator());
}
```

It is not important that `getAccelerator` is called before `driver.press`. It is not even important that `getAccelerator` is called. Rather what matters is that driver presses car’s accelerator. So you only need to validate driver.